# seleccionar palabras por la vocal 'a' con python utilizando for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

necesito sacar de una lista(list1) las palabras que contengan la vocal 'a' a otra lista(list2) que no contiene nada.
todo esto utilizando python con for loop.

```py
lis1: ['adios','merengue','hola']
list2 :[]

for x in list1:
 if x == a in list1
```

ayuda con el ejercicio

Comment: Con lo que muestras ya tienes casi todo, solo agregar el lamento que cumple la condición a la nueva lista y eso se hace de varias formas que te toca investigar, pero lo más común que puedes usar es el método `.append` de las listas

Comment: `lista2 = [x for x in lista1 if 'a' in x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = ['adios','merengue','hola']
list2 = []

for word in list1:
    if 'a' in word:
        list2.append(word)

print(list2)
```

El código hará una iteración por cada palabra en `list1`, comprobará si contiene la vocal `'a'`, y si es así, agrega la palabra a `list2`.

Después de que el ciclo se haya completado, `list2` contendrá las palabras `['adios', 'hola']`.

Ten en cuenta que la palabra clave in se utiliza para comprobar si una subcadena (en este caso, la vocal 'a') se encuentra dentro de una cadena (en este caso, la palabra de `list1`). El método `append()` se utiliza para agregar un elemento al final de una lista.

Comment: Y eso que hace??

Comment: quiero sacar las palabras que contenga la vocal 'a' de la lista y imprimirla en en la otra lista

Comment: @Lagger.bash entonces además de meterlas en la otra lista sacalas con el método `remove`